# If text doesn't include one of these two (.com or .info), or if it doesnt include (@)

Tags: java

```
else if(!jTextField4.getText().endsWith(".com") || 
    !jTextField4.getText().endsWith(".info") || 
    !jTextField4.getText().contains("@"))
```

I tried using this code but it doesn't work. I need it for my college project using NetBeans. I am a beginner by the way.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You might look for De Morgan's law to "swap" the `and` and `or` operators to make it more clear how you want to check your conditions. As of now this boolean expression will **always** be `true` as the text will either *not* end with `.com` or *not* end with `.info` and there is no way to prevent this (it can't end with both strings at the same time).

Comment: I see that there are a lot of answer but it is difficult to understand what you want. Can you give some examples with sText value and result ? I will also simplify your question so that is simple to read. I hope that other users can adapt their answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really have a question and you're not telling us the goal, so this is just a guess, but I suspect your logic is wrong. You probably want something more like

```
if (!(jTextField4.getText().endsWith(".com") || jTextField4.getText().endsWith(".info)) && !jtextField4.getText().contains("&"))
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm not shure if the properties of String works directly on getText of a jField. And on the "else if" clausule you need to negate the individual value of each one, try this

```
// add this line before if-else 
String field4Str = jTextField4.getText();
//code...
else if ( 
    (! field4Str.endsWith(".com")) || 
    (! field4Str.endsWith(".info")) || 
    (! field4Str.contains("@"))
){
// code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern *not case1 or not case2 or not...*  is **wrong**.
As it is always true. (This was already commented: at least one case is false.) The `||` must be changed into `&&`s.

And introducing a variable for the repeated string helps reading, and might have helped.

Answer (score 0):

```
else if((!jTextField4.getText().endsWith(".com") || 
!jTextField4.getText().endsWith(".info")) &&
!jTextField4.getText().contains("@"))
```

Comment: Maybe a little more explanation can help to inderstand the code